# What kind of a formula is this and does it belong to combinatorics?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, binomial-theorem

$$ x^n-y^n $$

Hi I have a limit to calculate with this formula and I don't know where it belongs,I only know the binomial combination.Is this formula related to combinatorics?

$$\lim_{x \to 1}  \frac {x^n-1}{x^m-1} $$

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^n-1-n(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} $$

I have 2 limits and I do not understand where $x^n-y^n$ come from. I've searched my textbooks and I couldn't find anything about this.I know that this is special factoring but I haven't found a proof of this type. Can someone help me and explain to me how these 2 powers are related to special factoring ?

$$ x^n-y^n = (x-1)*(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1) $$

$$ y^n=1 $$

How did this formula appeared? I don't understand this solution and this solution is related to the 2 limits!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^2+\dots+y^{n-1})$$
(you can check it by expanding the right hand side: almost all terms cancel pairwise),
hence
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\dots+1),$$
so that
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n-1}{x^m-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+1}{x^{m-1}+x^{m-2}+\dots+1}=\frac nm$$
(the special case $m=1$ will be used at the end of the calculation below),
and
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n-1-n(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}+\dots+1-n}{x-1}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{n-1}-1}{x-1}+\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^{n-2}-1}{x-1}+\dots+\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-1}{x-1}$$
$$=(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+0=\frac{(n-1)n}2.$$

Comment: so this is related to the binomial of Newton(combinatorics)?

Comment: No, it is direct algebraic calculation: please see the two first lines in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Difference of Two Squares

The formula $x^n-y^n$ is a difference of two squares. For example, if $n=2$ we can write
$$x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$$
The generalized difference of two squares for any two $n$th power is
$$x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$
writing this as a sum, we get
$$x^n-y^n = (x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}y^k$$

Note that when $y = 1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k} = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$

This is just to explain the 'special' factoring you aksed about.

---

@Anne_Bauval already gave the limits in their answer, namely

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{x^n-1}{x^m-1} = \frac{n}{m}$$
and
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{x^n-1 - n(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

---

### Relation to Combinatorics

This isn't directly related to combinatorics without defining what $x, y, n, m$ are. There are perhaps a few links

1. Is a link to the binomial coefficient $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{x^n-1 - n(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = {n \choose 2}$$
2. In the field of post quantum calculus one of the key building blocks of the field: the $(p, q)$-number is based off of $x^n-y^n$, and is defined as
   $$\frac{p^n-q^n}{p-q}$$
   which (when using the formula from above) yields
   $$\frac{p^n-q^n}{p-q} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^{n-1-k}q^k$$
   (although this is called post quantum 'calculus', it is a field of combinatorics in its own right)
3. Binet's formula

If we have the two roots of $x^2-x-1$ (golden ratio) denoted as $\phi_+, \phi_-$ then the nth Fibonacci number $F_n$ is
$$F_m = \frac{\phi_+^n-\phi_-^n}{\phi_+-\phi_-}$$

These are just some examples of potential relations to combinatorics